# Connecting to a Bluetooth Low Energy device from MAUI Android app

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, maui

Need to simply connect to a Bluetooth LE pressure sensor and read pressure values every few seconds.

All the Bluetooth LE libraries for MAUI appear to be open source and poorly supported with zero samples.  I'd be quite happy to pay for a solid library with support if someone can point me to one please?

Just finding a compilable sample that could achieve a connection with my device would be a massive step forward.

Have tried using several free libraries.  Some I can't get to compile and others refuse to locate the device or connect.

Answer (score 1):

> Need to simply connect to a Bluetooth LE pressure sensor

There is nothing simple about it.

You need to write platform specific code, and use dependency injection to make it usable by your app. The alternatives are those "poorly supported" libs.

However, judging by the way you speak of this, I seriously doubt that you understand what GATT, Service, Characteristic, Descriptor (and others) are.

And even if you find out, the next thing that you will notice, is that those devices do not simply answer "The pressure is 2".

I have been doing reverse engineering of such BLE devices in the past. It is serious amount of effort.

Someone is making those devices, contact him directly, and see what SDK he can offer you. (In one situation, they asked from us to order some amount of devices, before they provided it.) I guess it wont hurt you to try this as well.

Also, there are applications, that can list BLE devices, connect and expose what is available on the device. You will see GUIDs, but it is better than nothing. I suggest this will be your first step towards reverse engineering, if the above fails.

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for your comments HAH.  Yes, I'm beginning to understand I could have a long journey ahead of me.  I do understand the basics about services and characteristics identified by UUIDs and the fact that you have to mess around with returned values to get anything useable.  Luckily the supplier has provided documentation of the interface and also a compilable windows project.  It opens a serial port and performs read and write operations on the port.  Is there a way I can harness that windows code and make it work in MAUI targeting Android please?

Comment: @Sutts99 I cannot say. I do not know what you mean by "windows code". If it is C# it may be possible to be completely reused. Or it may need certain tweaks. Native code can also be used, thou it requires a bit more work. Java code wont be of much use, unless you decide to go for Android Studio. (Not really bad idea, actually. I do have project on Android Studio, as well on MAUI) I do not know your case well enough. I do not even understand what that COM port has to do with BLE.

Comment: Thanks HAH.  Yes, it's C# code to compile and run on windows devices.  I think you need to use a Bluetooth dongle to use it so the COM port must be to connect to that device.  Appreciate the pointers.  Thanks.